# Create a dir and save adb logs in it

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a new dir in my current dir and save adb logs in the new dir I just created. I am trying the following code but somehow the logs are overwritten each time I run it.I want to save all logs and not overwrite them.

```
use POSIX;
use Getopt::Long;
our $timestamp;
our $mainlog_filename;
our $ostype = $^O;
our $ProcessObj;
$SIG{'INT'} = 'INT_handler';
$SIG{'TERM'} = 'INT_handler';
$SIG{'ABRT'} = 'INT_handler';
$SIG{'QUIT'} = 'INT_handler';

if($^O eq 'MSWin32') { 
    $SIG{'BREAK'} = 'INT_handler';
    use Win32::Process;
}

$split_val = join(':', @ARGV[0..(@ARGV-1)]);

@split_val = split(':',$split_val);
$counter=1;
foreach $sno(@split_val)
{
print "Serial Number $counter is $sno\n";
$counter++;
}

# Hash to translate number to month name
my $monthhash = {
    1  => 'Jan',
    2  => 'Feb',
    3  => 'Mar',
    4  => 'Apr',
    5  => 'May',
    6  => 'Jun',
    7  => 'Jul',
    8  => 'Aug',
    9  => 'Sep',
    10 => 'Oct',
    11 => 'Nov',
    12 => 'Dec',
};


$currdir = `pwd`; 
chomp $currdir; # gets current directory
$currdir =~ s/ \/[^\/]+$//; # removes the last / and everything after it
$new_dir = "adb logs";
$perm = 755;


sub makeDir {
  if (-e "$new_dir"){ problem("Directory $new_dir already exists.\n") } # Checks for existing
  mkdir ($new_dir,$perm) || problem("Error making Directory $new_dir\n");
  print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
  print "$new_dir Directory has been created.\n";
  }
sub main
{
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
    $mon  = $mon + 1;
    $mday = sprintf("%02d", $mday) if $mday <= 9;
    my $date    = $monthhash->{$mon}.$mday;
    $timestamp=$date."_".$hour."_".$min;
    foreach $sno(@split_val)
    {
    chomp($sno);
      $mainlog_filename = "adblogs_".$sno."_".$timestamp.".txt";
    }

    makeDir() unless -d $new_dir;

    my $adbcommand_logcat;
    my $adb_install_apk;
    my $adb_install_testapk;

    if($ostype eq 'MSWin32') {
        system("title Android");

        foreach $sno(@split_val)
        {
        chomp($sno);
        print "$sno\n";


        chdir $new_dir;
        $adbcommand_logcat = "start \"Android-Logcat\" cmd /c \"adb -s $sno logcat -v time | tee ".$mainlog_filename."\"";
        chdir $currdir;
        $adb_install_apk = "adb install xyz.apk";
        $adb_install_testapk = "adb install xyzTest.apk";

    $cmd = "adb -s $sno get\-state";
    my $cmdop = qx/$cmd 2>&1/;


    print $cmdop;


      if($cmdop =~ m/device/i) {

            system($adb_install_apk);
            system($adb_install_testapk); 
            system($adbcommand_logcat); 
        }
     else {
        print "Device is offline\n";
    }

    }
}
}
sub terminate
{
    print "\nTerminating script ...\n";
    system("adb kill-server");
   #if($ostype eq 'MSWin32') {
   #   $ProcessObj->Kill(0);
  #  }
    exit 0;
}

sub INT_handler
{
    terminate(); 
    exit 0;
}


main();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want to use `tee -a ...` then?

Answer (score 3):

There is so much confusion in this script.

You did not `use strict; use warnings;` which helps you detect and prevent common errors. Put that at the top of every Perl script ASAP, and fix all errors which it finds. If you add `use diagnostics;` you get a longer explanation of each error message.

You are using global variables with `our`. There are few cases where this is required. More likely, you want lexical variables with `my`. Also, declare your variables in the tightest possible scope, and as close to their first use as possible. Declaring your variables up front does not increase readability.

Even if an `use` statement appears to be inside an `if`, it is always executed. These statements are not subject to normal control flow, because they are executed at compile time. For conditional loading, use the `if` pragma: `use if $^O eq "MSWin32", 'Win32::Process'`, although such conditional loading is not usually helpful.

`@ARGV[0..(@ARGV-1)]` is basically the same thing as `@ARGV`. Everything else is obfuscation. (There is a difference when used in a return value etc., but this is not relevant here).

If no element in `@ARGV` contains a colon, then `@split_val = split ':', join ':', @ARGV` is a very fancy way of writing `@split_val = @ARGV`, i.e. doing a copy. If the elements can contain colons, then `@split_val = map { split ':' } @ARGV` may be clearer.

When iterating over array elements *and* indices, it is better to iterate the indices, and access the array elements:

```
for my $i (1 .. @array) {
  print "The $i-th element has the value $array[$i-1]\n";
}
```

This is clearer than manually incrementing a `$counter`.

You seem to be doing your own date formatting. Check out the `strftime` function in the `POSIX` module. It seems you want to format your dates like `Jan28_19_45`. This could be achieved like

```
 use POSIX qw/strftime/;

 my $timestamp = strftime '%b%d_%H_%m', localtime;
```

Instead of concatenating strings with the `.` operator, it is often easier to read when you interpolate variables. E.g. `"foo ".$bar." baz"` can become `"foo $bar baz"`. To delimit your variable name, you can use a curly brace: `"foo".$bar."baz"` is the same as `"foo${bar}baz"`.

I can't see where you defined a `problem` function. Use `die` for fatal errors instead.

Assigning to the same variable in a loop only retains the last value:

```
my $foo;
for my $i (1 .. 3) {
  $foo = $i;
}
# $foo == 3, so let's write my $foo = 3 directly!
```

Unless your commands use shell operators like `|` or `>`, it is better to pass a *list* to `system` instead of a single string. This avoids shell interpolation issues. E.g.

```
system "echo", "|delimited text|", "{m,e,t,a}characters";
```

Do some error handling for `system`. One possibility is to `use autodie qw/:all/`.

`$new_dir = "adb logs";` – you never assign a different value, thus `mkdir` will never create a different directory. All this indirection with `-e` and `-d` is just confusing.

You only do actual work if you are on Windows. Remove all those `if ($ostype eq 'MSWin32')` and rather bail out if your script is useless on another OS: `BEGIN { $^O eq 'MSWin32' or die "This script can only be run on Windows" }`.

---

Now go, fix these issues, indent your code properly, make your script debuggable and come back if you still have problems after that. If you are in search for a good Perl tutorial, check out the list in the [Perl tagwiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info).

Comment: Thanks amon, This script is meant for Windows only. $new_rir - "adb logs" I just want to create the dir once if it does not exists already   and save log files in it.

Comment: The log file $mainlog_filename needs to be saved in $new_dir instead of current dir.

Comment: @user2526207 I would assume that your script actually does that, but it is hard to tell in the current form. My “answer” does not address your main problem, but lists various issues that should be rectified before the *actual* debugging can begin. I cannot comprehend your code because it is too confused – if we remove this confusion, the actual problem will become clear.